# Azure Api managament y kubernetes

Tags: api, azure

Tengo una api en kubernetes expuesta a través de NodePort, cuando trato de agregar la api en el azure api mangament a través de la opción OpenApiSpecification y url http://10.35.748.671:31285/swagger/v1/swagger.json me está mostrando el siguiente error:

Unable to download specified file. Please ensure the URL is valid and the file is publicly accessible.

La descripción de mi servicio es la siguiente:

```
Name:                     kservice

Namespace:                default

Labels:                   app=apis

Annotations:              <none>

Selector:                 app=apikb

Type:                     NodePort

IP:                       10.0.0.123

Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP

TargetPort:               80/TCP

**NodePort:                 <unset>  31285/TCP**

Endpoints:                10.35.748.671:80,10.35.748.697:80

Session Affinity:         None

External Traffic Policy:  Cluster

Events:                   <none>
```

¿Cómo puedo ver una api desplegada en Kubernete como NodePort en el Azure Api Managament?

Comment: Estás en la versión hispana de StackOverflow, traduce tu pregunta por favor :D

Answer (score 0):

Respondo mi pregunta. Para ver servicios del kubernetes expuestos a través de NodePort es necesario que la subnet del api management y la del Kubernetes sean la misma o que se puedan ver.

Otro punto es que para que se pueda ver desde una red privada los servicios NodePort es necesario que la versión del kubernetes sea 1.10.3 o superior.